# Collection was modified error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, one-to-many

I have a problem with deleting an object because it has relationship with other objects.
I am using MVC4 and Code First database approach.

Here are my model class :

```
 public class Product
{
    public Product() { }

    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool Istaxable { get; set; }
    public string DefaultImage { get; set; }
    public IList<Feature> Features { get; set; }
    public IList<Descriptor> Descriptors { get; set; }
    public IList<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public IList<Image> Images { get; set; }

    public Product(string name, decimal price, bool istaxable, string defaultImageFile)
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
        Istaxable = istaxable;
        DefaultImage = defaultImageFile;
        Categories = new List<Category>();
        Features = new List<Feature>();
        Descriptors = new List<Descriptor>();
        Images = new List<Image>();
    }
}

 public class Image
{

    public Image() { }

    public Image(string thumb, string full) : this(thumb, full, false) { }

    public Image(string thumb, string full, bool isDefault)
    {
        Thumb = thumb;
        IsDefault = isDefault;
        Full = full;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Thumb { get; set; }
    public string Full { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

And here is the code in my Product Controller :

```
// DELETE /api/product/5
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
    {

        var prd = Uow.Products.GetProductByIdIncludeAll(id);

        var images = prd.Images;
        if ( images.Count > 0 )
        {
            foreach(Image i in images)
            {
                Uow.Images.Delete(i);
            }
        }

        var descriptors = prd.Descriptors;
        if (descriptors.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Descriptor d in descriptors)
            {
                Uow.Descriptors.Delete(d);
            }
        }

        var features = prd.Features;
        if (features.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Feature f in features)
            {
                Uow.Features.Delete(f);
            }
        }

        Uow.Commit();

        Uow.Products.Delete(id);
        Uow.Commit();

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

Uow is a my Repository classes structured as a unit of work.

When I am trying to run the app it deletes the relationship object but not the product object because it says that the Collection have been modified.

How should I refactor this code to make it work É

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try to remove the first `Uow.Commit()` and do only one at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the underlying collection when you are using [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), I would suggest that you use a basic `for` statement.

from above MSDN link:

> The foreach statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the information that you want, but can not be used to add or remove items from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects. If you need to add or remove items from the source collection, use a for loop